# Через VS code работает, а через стандартный интерпретатор выдает ошибку

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code, интерпретатор, playsound

Всем добра! Написал программу. Через VS code все работает, а через стандартный интерпретатор выдает ошибку "Указанное устройство не открыто или не опознается интерфейсом MCI." Что может быть не так? Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from playsound import playsound
    import random

    ALPHABET = {'A': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-a.wav",
        'B': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-b.mp3",
        'C': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-c.mp3",
        'D': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-d.mp3",
        'E': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-e.mp3",
        'F': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-f.mp3",
        'G': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-g.mp3",
        'H': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-h.mp3",
        'I': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-i.mp3",
        'J': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-j.mp3",
        'K': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-k.mp3",
        'L': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-l.mp3",
        'M': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-m.mp3",
        'N': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-n.mp3",
        'O': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-o.mp3",
        'P': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-p.mp3",
        'Q': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-q.mp3",
        'R': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-r.mp3",
        'S': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-s.mp3",
        'T': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-t.mp3",
        'U': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-u.mp3",
        'V': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-v.mp3",
        'W': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-w.mp3",
        'X': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-x.mp3",
        'Y': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-y.mp3",
        'Z': "EnglishAlphabet/letter-z.mp3"}
    keys = []
    values = []
    for i, j in ALPHABET.items():
        keys.append(i)
        values.append(j)

    class Word():
        def __init__(self):
            self.word = ALPHABET[random.choice(list(ALPHABET))]
            self.answer = ''

        def newWord(self):
            self.word = ALPHABET[random.choice(list(ALPHABET))]
            return self.word    
    
        def playWord(self):
            playsound(self.word)    

        def checkAnswer(self):
            self.answer = txtAnswer.get()
            if ALPHABET[self.answer.upper()] == self.word:
                result.configure(text = "Верно!")
            else:
                result.configure(text = "Ошибка!")  

    word = Word()


    window = Tk()
    window.geometry("640x480")
    btnPlay = Button(window, text = "Играть", command = word.playWord)
    txtAnswer = Entry(window, width = 5)
    btnCheckAnswer = Button(window, text = "Проверить", command = word.checkAnswer) 
    result = Label(window, text = '')
    btnNewWord = Button(window, text = "Новая буква", command = word.newWord)

    btnPlay.grid(column = 1, row = 0)
    txtAnswer.grid(column = 2, row = 0)
    btnCheckAnswer.grid(column = 3, row = 0)
    result.grid(column = 4, row = 0)
    btnNewWord.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Скорее всего из `VS Code` у вас другое окружение питона вызывается. Нужно разобраться, где у вас какое окружение и вызывать из того, где работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело музыке, точнее в самом модуле. Нужна версия 1.2.2.

```
pip uninstall playsound
pip install playsound==1.2.2
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я попробую, но ведь это более старая версия

Comment: Еще раз спасибо. Все заработало. Странно, так как этот способ я пробовал в начале написания программы и не работало, возможно тогда было дело в чем-то другом. Тем не менее сейчас все работает, спасибо.